# std::cout << stringstream.str()->c_str() prints nothing

Tags: c++, stringstream, stdstring, libpcap, unsigned-char

in a function, that gets unsigned char && unsigned char length,

```
void pcap_callback(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr* pkthdr, const u_char* packet) 
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> vec(packet, packet+pkthdr->len); // optimized from foo.
    std::stringstream scp;
    for (int i=0;i<pkthdr->len;i++) {
        scp<<vec[i];
    }
    std::string mystr =  std::string(scp.rdbuf()->str());
    std::cout << "WAS: " << packet << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GOOD: " << scp.str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "BAD: "  << scp.str().c_str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "TEST: " << mystr.size() << std::endl;
    assert(mystr.size() == pkthdr->len); 
}
```

Results:

- WAS: prints nothing (guess there is a pointer to const.. case)
- GOOD: prints data
- BAD: prints nothing
- TEST, assert: prints that mystr.size() is equal to passed unsigned char size.

I tried:

- string.assign(scp.rdbuf());
- memcpy(char, scp.str(), 10);
- different methods of creating/allocating temporary chars, strings

No help.. it is wanted to get a *std::cout*'able *std::string* that contains data, (which was picked from *foo*, which was *unsigned char*, which was packet data).

Guessing either the original *foo* may not be null-terminated, or the problem is something like this - simple, but can't get in.. what are the things to look for here?

(this code is another attempt to use libpcap, just to print packets in C++ way, without using known C++ magic wrappers like libpcapp).

Comment: How is `std::cout << "BAD: "  << scp.str()->c_str() << std::endl;` even *compiling*??  The member function `std::stringstream::str()` does not return a pointer.  It returns an instance of `std::string`.

Comment: @Charles Salvia, ouch. got a mistype while trying to remember all faulty attempts to chew it.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be, bpf_u_int32.

Comment: @mhambra I mean, is it actually a valid number? Does the vector get filled?

Comment: From looking at your code, the only thing I can think of to explain this behavior is that `foo` contains a null byte, so when you print it as a C-string nothing is outputted.  But your implementation of iostreams prints out `std::string` by iterating over `std::string::length()` bytes and printing each character, including characters which appear after the null.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be, yes.. posted more code (not so minimal example), assert(foo_len > 10) and assert(foo_len < 2000) are valid, and in fact, the value is correct for the actual data.

Comment: @Charles Salvia, then, what is a best way to strip the trailing null byte from c_str(), so std::cout << c_str() would print the string?

Comment: or, what is a method to access std::string's data by byte, knowing the length? [ would print them per-char]

Comment: @mhambra, if your `packet` buffer is supposed to contain binary data (which it probably is, judging from the `u_char` type), you can't expect to be able to print it meaningfully to the console as text.  You need to iterate over each byte and output it as decimal or hex.

Comment: @mhambra: Err.. `std::basic_string<t>::operator[]`? Plus it's a valid STL container so you can use anything that would normally iterate over an stl container (i.e. `std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a quick test, throw in a check for `scp.str().size() == strlen(scp.str().c_str())` to see if there are embedded '\0' characters in the string, which is what I suspect is happening.

Comment: suspected the same.. and yes, assertion failed.. same happens for scp.str().data(), now it's a question, how to forward a null-byte elements down to some kind of hex print.

Comment: `strlen(scp.str().c_str())` is actually zero.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going about this the wrong way.  It looks like you're dealing with binary data here, in which case you can't expect to meaningfully output it to the screen as text.  What you really need is a *hex dump*.

```
const unsigned char* ucopy = packet;
std::ios_base::fmtflags old_flags = std::cout.flags();
std::cout.setf(std::ios::hex, std::ios::basefield);

for (const unsigned char* p = ucopy, *e = p + pkthdr->len; p != e; ++p) {
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<unsigned>(*p) << " ";
}

std::cout.flags(old_flags);
```

This will output the data byte-by-byte, and let you examine the individual hex values of the binary data.  A null byte will simply be output as `00`.

Comment: nice.. what about appending the byte values to a `static char *`, effectively copyinng the string - you think that a kind of `char[len] = strdup(?_cast<const char *>())` would do it?

Answer (score 1):

Check `std::cout.good()` after the failed output attempt. My guess is that there's some failure on output (i.e. trying to write a nonprintable character to the console), which is setting `failbit` on `cout`.

Also check to ensure the string does not start with a `NULL`, which would cause empty output to be the expected behavior :)

(Side note, please use `reinterpret_cast` for `unsigned char *ucopy = (unsigned char*)packet;` if you're in C++ ;) )

Comment: BAD packet is: cout Good 1 Eof 0 Fail 0 Bad 0; used `const_cast` because the original argument is const..

Comment: @mhambra Rather than using const cast, you should make the pointer be a `const unsigned char *`, and remove the const_cast.